# knitr: Overwrite chunk options with hook function

Tags: r, knitr

Motivated by https://gist.github.com/yihui/2629886#file-knitr-checkpoint-rnw, I want to create a knitr hook that can overwrite certain options of a knitr chunk:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup>>=
knit_hooks$set(checkpoint = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (!before) {
      opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, include = TRUE)
      opts_current$set(echo = TRUE, include = TRUE) ## no effect
  }
})
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, include = TRUE, checkpoint = "foobar")
@

<<example-a, echo=FALSE>>=
x = 1
@

<<example-b, echo=TRUE>>=
x = 2
@

\end{document}
```

Globally, all code chunks are displayed in the output.  The display of the output of the first chunk is disabled through the chunk option `echo=FALSE`.  This should be reset by the hook 'checkpoint'.  However, this is not the case - most probably because the chunk options are evaluated before the hook gets called.

Is there another solution to this?

Comment: The options must be evaluated before the hook can be called at all, as the hook is one of the options. I don't have a solution, but maybe you can get some inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095113/r-knitr-possible-to-programmatically-modify-chunk-labels

Comment: @ROLO: I was hoping that modifying 'opts_current' would have an effect (http://yihui.name/knitr/objects), but it does not have an effect at any level.