# How to get chunk name in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to set the chunk option "eval" based on a list of chunk names. Is there a function to get the chunk name in knitr, e.g. chunk_name?

This is my minimum example with fake function name "chunk_name".

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
eval_chunks <- c('chunk1')
```

```{r chunk1, eval=chunk_name() %in% eval_chunks}
plot(cars)
```


```{r chunk2, eval=chunk_name() %in% eval_chunks}
plot(cars)
```
````

Thanks for any suggestions. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Assuming chunk names don't  change, you could create a named logical vector `eval_chunk <- c(chunk1 = TRUE, chunk2 = FALSE)` and then say `{r chunk1, eval = eval_chunk["chunk1"]}`.

Comment: One could try employing hooks, too.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I had the same idea, but the problem [noted in a comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687728/knitr-overwrite-chunk-options-with-hook-function#comment38286506_24687728), is that chunk options are evaluated before hooks are called, so that doesn't really work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Knitr provided labels inside a chunk since 2012 (need more Google, https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/73).

This is my sample Rmd file:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library(knitr)
eval_chunks <- c('chunk1', 'chunk3')
```

```{r chunk1, eval=opts_current$get("label") %in% eval_chunks}
print(opts_current$get("label"))
```


```{r chunk2, eval=opts_current$get("label") %in% eval_chunks}
print(opts_current$get("label"))
```


```{r chunk3, eval=opts_current$get("label") %in% eval_chunks}
print(opts_current$get("label"))
```
````

Comment: I am trying to understand why the need of these chunk names. Aren't they all executed by default?

Comment: They can be used as a literate progress bar while rendering the Rmd.

Comment: @EduardoReis chunk labels are also used as label references for figures and tables in `Rnw` documents compiled to latex. These are useful to write reproducible reports or publications.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution is imperfect because it requires a bit of care in making sure the correct chunks are evaluated, but it gets around the problem that chunk options are evaluated before hooks are called. In short, it doesn't use a hook, but instead uses the fact that chunk options can be R expressions. In this case, a function `e()` is used that relies on a global counter variable to dictate whether a particular chunk should be evaluated. Because chunks are evaluated in order, this works. In the below example, `chunk1` and `chunk3` are evaluated, but the others are not.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library("knitr")
.i <- 2 # `setup` is the first chunk, so start at 2
.x <- all_labels() %in% c("chunk1", "chunk3")
e <- function(){
    d <- .x[.i]
    .i <<- .i + 1
    d
}
```

```{r chunk1, eval=e()}
x <- 1
x
```

```{r chunk2, eval=e()}
x <- 2
x
```

```{r chunk3, eval=e()}
x <- 3
x
```

```{r chunk4, eval=e()}
x <- 4
x
```
````

Comment: "Because chunks are evaluated in order". Is it the case though? (cf `dependson`)

Comment: @baptiste I wouldn't want to try this in a complex document.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your suggestion. I agree with your point about the complex document (in my case), especially when adding/removing chunks.

Comment: Which consideration let you use .i rather than i in your code?