# How to produce markdown document for each row of dataframe in R

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to produce either 1 markdown document with subdocuments from each row of a dataframe or produce nrows number of markdown documents from a dataframe. The markdown document is template.Rmd.

I think that it should work to create a for loop, but when I try to do this, `by(dataFrame, 1:nrow(dataFrame), function(row) knit(file = "/Users/path/template.Rmd"))` I get an error that the input ended unexpectedly.

```
Quitting from lines 23-26 (Preview-e0d353674d36.Rmd) 
Error in knit(file = "/Users/path/template.Rmd") : 
  unused argument (file = "/Users/path/template.Rmd")
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> tapply -> lapply -> FUN -> FUN -> knit

Execution halted
```

I tried using the same awesome approach solved by @Yihui to programmatically reference text with knitr-expand detailed here: [R knitr: Possible to programmatically modify chunk labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095113/r-knitr-possible-to-programmatically-modify-chunk-labels)

From that solution, we have two .Rmd files, My report and Template
My report looks like:

````
# My report

```{r}
data(mtcars)
cyl.levels <- unique(mtcars$cyl)
```

## Generate report for each level of cylinder variable
```{r, include=FALSE}
src <- lapply(cyl.levels, function(ncyl) knit_expand(file = "template.Rmd"))
```

`r knit(text = unlist(src))`
````

Template looks like:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
cat("### {{ncyl}} cylinders")
```

```{r mpg-histogram-{{ncyl}}cyl}
hist(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == {{ncyl}}], 
  main = paste({{ncyl}}, "cylinders"))
```

```{r weight-histogam-{{ncyl}}cyl}
hist(mtcars$wt[mtcars$cyl == {{ncyl}}], 
  main = paste({{ncyl}}, "cylinders"))
```
````

This solution produces a single markdown document with a subdocument (at heading level 2) for each level of cylinder. However, I am trying to create a report that fetches a .csv and then creates and modifies a dataframe and produces content for each row of another dataframe.

What I think I am stuck on is how to use the value in {{ncyl}} to programmatically refer to rows of a database. I would like to be able to use the levels of {{ncyl}} to go and do stuff with the related rows in the dataframe mtcars (assuming that it only had rows == levels{{ncyl}} for this example).

While `data(mtcars)`, does have more rows than levels of cylyinder, R stores the value of {{ncyl}} as an integer. So, you can call `mtcars$gear[[{{ncyl}}]]` and get the value of gear for the {{ncyl}} row.

Why then, when we add that into our template.Rmd, it fails?

Forgive me, it doesn't fail, it will give us `gear <- mtcars$gear[[{{ncyl}}]]` but we cannot then create a chunk of gear, like ```` ```{r this-gear-{{gear}}} ````.

This works

````
```{r}
gear <- mtcars$gear[[{{ncyl}}]]
gear
```

```{r, results='asis'}
cat("### {{ncyl}} cylinders")
```

```{r mpg-histogram-{{ncyl}}cyl}
hist(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == {{ncyl}}], 
  main = paste({{ncyl}}, "cylinders"))
```

```{r weight-histogam-{{ncyl}}cyl}
hist(mtcars$wt[mtcars$cyl == {{ncyl}}], 
  main = paste({{ncyl}}, "cylinders"))
```
````

This does not work

````
```{r}
gear <- mtcars$gear[[{{ncyl}}]]
gear
```

```{r, results='asis'}
cat("### {{ncyl}} cylinders")
```

```{r mpg-histogram-{{ncyl}}cyl}
hist(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == {{ncyl}}], 
  main = paste({{ncyl}}, "cylinders"))
```

```{r weight-histogam-{{ncyl}}cyl}
hist(mtcars$wt[mtcars$cyl == {{ncyl}}], 
  main = paste({{ncyl}}, "cylinders"))
```
```{r {{gear}}}
gear
```
````

Giving the error

```
Quitting from lines 10-12 (Preview-e0d32d687661.Rmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'gear' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... knit_expand -> inline_exec -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

I think I am approaching the main problem "How do I create a markdown document for each row of a dataframe?" wrong with the knit-expand feature.

Can someone help me understand:
1. How to solve the main problem
2. Why the {{gear}} does not work within template.Rmd?

So, I still don't understand (2), but I think that @daroczig has gotten me close to understanding one way to solve the main problem. I don't think this is too unique of a problem, and I assume that there is a way to solve it without `brew` or `pander` or `rapport`.  In any case, I took the brew approach and do something with a few lines of a dataframe. It throws an error. Note I am not doing anything sensible with this code, just limiting the `mtcars` to 3 rows so I don't get too much output, and then creating another, lame, dataframe within the  `for`  loop.

```
# My report

<%
mtcars1 <- mtcars[1:3,]
mtcars1$type <- c('red','blue','green')
t.levels <- unique(mtcars1$type)
for (ty in t.levels) {
p <- subset(mtcars1,type == ty) 
x <- rep(p, 4)
short <- paste0(p$gear, p$mpg)
%>

### <%= short %> blah

<%=
hist(x$mpg, main = paste(short, "blah"))
%>

<% } %>
```

This is just a little lame modification of the solution proposed below by @daroczig. It works if we name it `demo.brew` and call it from  `Pandoc.brew('demo.brew', output = tempfile(), convert = 'html')`. Making one silly example.

(3) Is there an example of how to do this without brew? I'm curious.

Answer to (3) Yes. This works with a for loop that calls the variable instead of row num

```
varlist <- unique(df$variable)
for (var in varlist) {
    try(knit2html(input= '/Users/path/template.Rmd',
                  output=paste0('/Users/path/template',var,'.html')))
```

Works where the loop from 1:nrow() did not.

Comment: Promoting `pander` a bit, you might try the `<% ... %>` type of tags in the `brew`-like syntax for conditional calls or loops in a markdown document: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc

Comment: I hope that I can get up to speed quickly on the brew <code><% ... %></code> syntax. I took a look at the link, and I'm starting from 0 on that approach. If I can figure it out, I'll post the solution here.

Comment: pls see my below answer, I hope you might find that useful. Feel free to let me know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution with `pander` -- based on my above comment:

```
# My report

<%
cyl.levels <- unique(mtcars$cyl)
for (ncyl in cyl.levels) {
%>

### <%= ncyl %> cylinders

<%=
hist(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == ncyl], main = paste(ncyl, "cylinders"))
hist(mtcars$wt[mtcars$cyl == ncyl], main = paste(ncyl, "cylinders"))
%>

<% } %>
```

To brew this file (named as `demo.brew`), run:

```
Pandoc.brew('demo.brew')
```

Or to get e.g. a MS Word document:

```
Pandoc.brew('demo.brew', output = tempfile(), convert = 'docx')
```

---

**Update**: I've just realized that you need separate documents for the categories. For this end, I'd suggest my other package, `rapport`,  a try, which focuses on exactly statistical report templates. Quick example:

```
<!--head
meta:
  title: Demo for @Jessi
  author: daroczig
  description: This is a demo
  packages: ~
inputs:
- name: ncyl
  class: integer
  standalone: TRUE
  required: TRUE
head-->

### <%= ncyl %> cylinders

<%=
hist(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl == ncyl], main = paste(ncyl, "cylinders"))
hist(mtcars$wt[mtcars$cyl == ncyl], main = paste(ncyl, "cylinders"))
%>
```

So this above document (`demo.rapport`) is a [rapport](http://rapport-package.info/) template, which has a YAML header for the metadata and inputs (which acts like parameters/arguments in R functions), then the body can include markdown and R code in `brew` syntax with `pander`. Now you can easily call this report template with a simple call, e.g. for 4 cylinders:

```
> rapport('demo.rapport', ncyl = 4)

### _4_ cylinders

![](plots/rapport--home-daroczig-projects-demo.rapport-6-1.png)
![](plots/rapport--home-daroczig-projects-demo.rapport-6-2.png)
```

And to produce a MS Word file for all cylinders, try this:

```
for (ncyl in (2:4)*2) {
    rapport.docx('/home/daroczig/projects/demo.rapport', ncyl = ncyl)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @daroczig  I tried this, and it looks like it ran, but I can't find the output. Here is what I got `> Pandoc.brew('demo.brew')
# My report

### _6_ cylinders

![](/var/folders/j9/2bx62h3j12n5ssr7w15kd84m0000gp/T//RtmpEaQcxi/plots/e0d369fb5e79.png)![](/var/folders/j9/2bx62h3j12n5ssr7w15kd84m0000gp/T//RtmpEaQcxi/plots/e0d375f7904a.png)

### _4_ cylinders

![](/var/folders/j9/2bx62h3j12n5ssr7w15kd84m0000gp/T//RtmpEaQcxi/plots/e0d3721ffbea.png)![](/var/folders/j9/2bx62h3j12n5ssr7w15kd84m0000gp/T//RtmpEaQcxi/plots/e0d311d3fa2f.png)
` etc.   If I use the `convert = 'docx'` I do get a file.

Comment: @Jessi sorry, probably I misunderstood the question. Please see the updated answer. I hope that might be useful.

Comment: That is pretty neat, @daroczig! I can get this to work like you show for each level of mtcars$cylinder. I am having a little trouble applying it to my own real-world project (where I need to get a row based on a level and then use that to do something else), but maybe you have a simple solution. I'll recreate the problem in an edit to my question.

Comment: Ok. I was able to make this work for my real world project - yay! Thanks! However, @daroczig, the pander.brew changes the format of my figures that I have precisely coded in `ggplot()`. Is there a way to override this "feature"?

Comment: @Jessi yeah, you can disable that feature by `evalsOptions('graph.unify', FALSE)`. For more details, please see http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#pander-options