# How to create separate R markdown paragraphs/pages for each row of data

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm new to Markdown, and I want to create a PDF report that has separate paragraphs (or pages will be even better) for each row of data in a data frame. There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407307/how-to-produce-markdown-document-for-each-row-of-dataframe-in-r), but I can't seem to replicate the answer.

Here is my sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Company = c("Uber", "AT&T", "Ford"),
  Stock.Ticker = c("UBER", "T", "F"),
  Price = c(61, 26, 11),
  Date = c("01/11/2021","01/13/2021","1/21/2021"),
  Description = c("Uber Technologies, Inc. develops and operates proprietary technology applications.",
                  "AT&T Inc. provides telecommunication, media, and technology services worldwide.",
                  "Ford Motor Company designs, manufactures, markets, and services a range of Ford trucks, cars, sport utility vehicles.")
)
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
[Uber Technologies, Inc. develops and operates proprietary technology applications.] [Uber]'s stock ticker is [UBER]. As of [01/11/2021], the stock price is $[61].


[AT&T Inc. provides telecommunication, media, and technology services worldwide.] [AT&T]'s stock ticker is [T]. As of [01/13/2021], the stock price is $[26].


[Ford Motor Company designs, manufactures, markets, and services a range of Ford trucks, cars, sport utility vehicles.] [fORD]'s stock ticker is [f]. As of [01/21/2021], the stock price is $[11].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to output the results of your code chunk with the chunk option `results='asis'` and `cat()` the output so that you are able to essentially write the necessary LaTeX directly.

Note, I had to escape the ampersand in the two AT&Ts with `\\` because the ampersand is a special character in LaTeX and needs to be escaped with a `\` and we need to escape that backslash with another backslash to represent a single backslash in an R character. There is an identical issue for getting the two `\newline` inserted in the final LaTeX.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
df <- data.frame(
  Company = c("Uber", "AT\\&T", "Ford"),
  Stock.Ticker = c("UBER", "T", "F"),
  Price = c(61, 26, 11),
  Date = c("01/11/2021","01/13/2021","1/21/2021"),
  Description = c("Uber Technologies, Inc. develops and operates proprietary technology applications.",
                  "AT\\&T Inc. provides telecommunication, media, and technology services worldwide.",
                  "Ford Motor Company designs, manufactures, markets, and services a range of Ford trucks, cars, sport utility vehicles.")
)

with(df, cat(sprintf(
  "%s %s's stock ticker is %s. As of %s, the stoke price is $%s.\\newline\\newline",
  Description, Company, Stock.Ticker, Date, Price
)))
```
````

Comment: Thanks! How can I get rid of the `[]` in the output file? I used it in my example to show that they are from the data frame. And what would be the code for a new paragraph?

Comment: I removed the `[]`s from the `sprintf()` format argument and swapped the `\\newpage` for two `\\newline`s to get new paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop.

```
for (company in df$company) {

   cat ( paste(
       df$description[df$company == company],
       company,
       df$Stock.Ticker))

   cat ("\n\\newpage")
}
```

Comment: I get the codes in the output file instead of the paragraphs.