# Knitr : automated figure numbering in the file names

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When compiling knitr reports, I would like to automatically change the name of the files (eg label-1.pdf) saved on the disc to include the automated numbering of the figures captions (eg Figure-054.pdf).

Example :

````
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,  fig.path = 'Figures/', fig.cap = '  ', fig.pos = "H")
```

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

```{r cars}
plot(cars)
```

```{r, fig.cap = 'pressure'}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r}
summary(iris)
```

```{r}
plot(iris)
plot(iris[,1] ~ iris[,5])
```
````

I obtain 4 file names

```
cars-1.pdf
unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf
unnamed-chunk-4-1.pdf
unnamed-chunk-4-2.pdf
```

I would like to obtain instead something like this (i.e. corresponding to the numbering in the pdf report) :

```
Figure-001.pdf
Figure-002.pdf
Figure-003.pdf
Figure-004.pdf
```

I know that the figures names can be changed with `fig.process` `knitr` option. But I don't know how I can capture the automated figure number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question comes up at the top of Google, and does not yet have a real solution after 6 years, here is what I did to solve the OP's problem. It uses the `fig.process` knitr hook to rename the figures as they are created.

The magic is that the figure number `n` is stored in the parent environment of the `fig.process` function, and incremented with the `<<-` assignment operator each time the function is called.

Put this in your setup code chunk.

```
make_plot_namer <- function(prefix="Figure-", n=1L, width=2){
  function(x){
    x2 <- file.path(dirname(x), 
                    paste0(prefix, 
                           formatC(n, width=width, flag="0"),
                           ".", 
                           tools::file_ext(x)))
    n <<- n + 1L
    if (file.rename(x, x2)) x2 else x
  }
}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.process = make_plot_namer(width=3))
```

Comment: Fantastic ! Thank you !! Note that in my use case the numbering was incorrect because I always use the option `opts_chunk$set(dev = c("cairo_pdf", "png"))` to get each figure both in pdf and png format. I modified your function to get a number increment every two usage.

Comment: This is a great answer, but readers should be warned that `<<-` can have unexpected results when used by those who don't understand it - it will overwrite any variables named `n` in the environment in which this function is called. To avoid this, use `assign` in conjunction with a separate environment, as demonstrated in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dave-lovell/39557a1b109975214d1060851a9a5f33). @Grady I'm happy to add alternative code to your answer that implements this functionality should you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of Grady W's answer to rename the figures correctly when you use the following option (to get each figure both in pdf and png format) :

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = c("cairo_pdf", "png"), echo = TRUE,  fig.path = 'Figures/', fig.cap = '  ', fig.pos = "H")`

```r
make_plot_namer <- function(prefix="Figure-", width=2) {
    n <- 0L  # Initialize n to 0
    counter <- 0L  # Initialize a counter variable to 0
    
    function(x) {
        if (counter %% 2 == 0) {
            # Increment n every 2 uses
            n <<- n + 1L
        }
        
        x2 <- file.path(dirname(x), 
                        paste0(prefix, 
                               formatC(n, width=width, flag="0"),
                               ".", 
                               tools::file_ext(x)))
        
        if (file.rename(x, x2)) {
            counter <<- counter + 1L  # Increment the counter after renaming
            x2
        } else {
            x
        }
    }
}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.process = make_plot_namer(width=3))
```

Answer (score -1):

I have part of the answer.

You have to name your chunks accordingly:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,  fig.path = 'Figures/', fig.cap = '  ', fig.pos = "H")
```

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

```{r Figure1}
plot(cars)
```

```{r Figure2, fig.cap = 'pressure'}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r }
summary(iris)
```

```{r Figure3}
plot(iris)

```

```{r Figure4}
plot(iris[,1] ~ iris[,5])
```
````

Ideally, create one figure per chunk.
I don't know yet how to get rid of the extra numbers `knitr` adds at the end of the chunk name.

Comment: Thanks @FabianCid but this is not a viable solution. At each time you insert a new graph or change the order of the graphs you must re-edit all chunk labels by hand...

Comment: I think it is viable, but not robust. To make it more robust, you can use [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095113/r-knitr-possible-to-programmatically-modify-chunk-labels)