# Can knitr add an index to identically named chunks?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

My knitr document consists of a single chunk which loops a parameterized child RMD into a long string object, *out*, using the knitr::knit_child() function. Next the *out* object is pasted verbatim as:

```
`r paste(out, collapse='\n')`
```

Is it possible for knitr to index the chunks in the child RMDs? For example, if the same chunk name is used repeatedly: *map*, *map*, *map*, ... could knitr automatically append the chunk names: *map*, *map-1*, *map-2*, ..., *map-n*?

As it stands, each iteration overwrites the chunk. Thus the content reflects only the last iteration. Not using labels is an effective stop-gap   but doing so prevents the handy use of reference R scripts for the children.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R knitr: Possible to programmatically modify chunk labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095113/r-knitr-possible-to-programmatically-modify-chunk-labels)