# Reuse R child Rmd files - error: duplicate chunk labels

Tags: r, duplicates, markdown, chunks

I wrote an Rmd Markdown file **main.Rmd** which works on the basis of the data of a certain logfile (**logfile1.Rda**):

```
load("logfile1.Rda")
```

In this main.Rmd I refer to several child chunks:

```
{r child = 'child1.Rmd'}
```

and

```
{r child = 'child2.Rmd'}
```

and so on...

Now, I want to refer to a second logfile (**logfile2.Rda**):

```
load("logfile2.Rda")
```

and to reuse the child Rmd files again:

```
{r child = 'child1.Rmd'}
```

and

```
{r child = 'child2.Rmd'}
```

and so on...

But, as expected, there is the "duplicate chunk labels" warning.

Do you have an idea, how to reuse my child Rmd files which includes several chunks?

Comment: Does this help: `options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")`

Comment: I already tried it, but nothing happened. **Where** do I have to add this?

Comment: Nothin happens ...

Comment: Not sure, It should have worked, read it here : https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/duplicate-label.html

Comment: I cannot add it in my Rprofile, because I want others to reproduce my stuff. And adding it into the main.Rmd doesn't work

Comment: How about assigning numbers for chunks in your main.Rmd (i <- 1 for logfile 1 and after that i <- 2 for logfile 2) and then using them in the child as chunk name like ```{r chunk{{i}} ,eval = TRUE,  results = "asis", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}` At least this worked for me when looping to create some plots with the same child.rmd You would need to use knit_expand in this case e.g. `knit_expand(text = readLines('child.rmd'), encoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: Works! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095113/r-knitr-possible-to-programmatically-modify-chunk-labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found a solution:

```
load("logfile1.Rda")
z <- 1
```

```
src <- lapply(z, function(z) knitr::knit_expand(file = "child1.Rmd"))
```

`r knitr::knit(text = unlist(src))`

```
src <- lapply(z, function(z) knitr::knit_expand(file = "child2.Rmd"))
```

`r knitr::knit(text = unlist(src))`

```
load("logfile2.Rda")
z <- 1
```

```
src <- lapply(z, function(z) knitr::knit_expand(file = "child1.Rmd"))
```

`r knitr::knit(text = unlist(src))`

```
src <- lapply(z, function(z) knitr::knit_expand(file = "child2.Rmd"))
```

`r knitr::knit(text = unlist(src))`

Within the child-files I added `{{z}}` to each chunk label.